# Creating directed graph from flat list

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, dependencies

I would like to create graph. My requirements are:

I have shared resources which are using for scheduling.

```
 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9
```

each of this can be combined to create node.

so I can have nodes such like these:

```
 [1,3],[2],[5,7,6,9] //[...] means that is one node (and can be complex)
                     //[...] is one job which have assigned multiple resources
```

Basicly what I need is to schedule dependand jobs which operates on shared resources. All happen concurrently, that's why I need this tree to be able to iterate on jobs, run free jobs in few threads (f.e 8 threads), wait for jobs to complete and run their dependand job.

So I implement an algorithm to create graph from flat list. These flat list looks like this:

```
    var nodes = new List<IDependencyJobNode>()
    {
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 1 }, ()=>{})),
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 2 }, ()=>{})),
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 1, 5, 4, 8 }, ()=>{})),
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 2, 3, 7, 9 }, ()=>{})),
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 8, 2 }, ()=>{})),
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 5, 7 }, ()=>{})),
        new DependandJobNode(new DependandJob(new List<int> { 5, 8 }, ()=>{})),
    };
```

However I have problem with such case

```
  [1]            [2]
   |              |
   v              v
 [1,5,4,8]     [2,3,7,9]
   |      \        |
   v       \ ------v
  [5,7]          [8,2]
     \            /
      \          /
          [5,8]
```

node **[5,8]** will be traversing 2 times, one starting from **[1]** and second time from **[2]** which give me four parents (parents are unnecessary duplicated)

Here is my implementation

```
public class TreeBuilder
{
    private IEnumerable<IDependencyJobNode> jobs;
    public int Depth { get; private set; }
    private int currentLevel;

    public IDependencyJobNode Root{ get; private set; }

    public TreeBuilder(IEnumerable<IDependencyJobNode> jobs)
    {
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.Depth = 0;
    }

    public void Create(IDependencyJobNode root)
    {

        var depths = new List<int> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Count(); ++i) {
            depths.Add(Insert(root, jobs.ElementAt (i), Depth + 1));
        }

        this.Depth = depths.Max ();

        this.Root = root;
    }

    public int Insert(IDependencyJobNode root, IDependencyJobNode job, int depth){
        var insertAsChild = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < root.Childs.Count(); ++i){
            var rootElement = root.Childs.ElementAt (i);
            if (HasCommonGpio (rootElement, job)) {
                depth = Insert (rootElement, job, depth + 1);
                insertAsChild = false;
            }
        }
        if (insertAsChild == true) {
            job.Parents.Add(root);
            root.AddChild (job);
        }
        return depth;
    }

    private static bool HasCommonGpio(IDependencyJobNode root, IDependencyJobNode job)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < root.Job.UsedGpio.Count (); ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < job.Job.UsedGpio.Count (); ++j) {
                if (root.Job.UsedGpio.ElementAt (i) == job.Job.UsedGpio.ElementAt (j)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return HasCommonGpio (root.Childs, job);
    }

    private static bool HasCommonGpio(IEnumerable<IDependencyJobNode> roots, IDependencyJobNode job)
    {
        if (roots == null || !roots.Any ()) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (var root in roots) {
            if (HasCommonGpio (root, job)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't cope with this, Is there any general algorithm how to implement such graphs with taking care of such complex cases? I don't know how to make it work, maybe someone would share some ideas?